# Add validation data on pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

Below I split my data on train and test and then load into a tensordataset. Which is a straightforward way to add a validation split?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0, stratify = y)

train_data = TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_train), torch.from_numpy(y_train))
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)

test_data = TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_test), torch.from_numpy(y_test))
test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a more straightforward way than the one that you are using right now, at least not without some other framework which sits on top of the pytorch (such as fastai). Unless you want to manually compute the cut points, shuffle your data, and make the corresponding splits (but this simple procedure does not handle the stratification).

Using your approach, you can further split the train set into 2 (train and validation)

```
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0, stratify = y)
```

One thing to note here is that you will need to adjust the `test_size` according to your needs (using 0.2 twice in a row will not result in 60/20/20 split).

Once you have `X_train`, `X_valid`, and `X_test` splits, you can simply create the 3rd `DataLoader` for your validation set.

```
valid_data = TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_valid), torch.from_numpy(y_valid))
valid_loader = DataLoader(valid_data, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Just a few notes:

- unlike in the case of the training set, you don't need to shuffle your validation and test sets, therefore you can set `shuffle=False` in the `DataLoader`
- you don't need to use the same batch size in each `DataLoader`, using larger batch sizes for validation is preferrable if your HW can handle it; computing with a larger batch size will be faster without side-effects since the gradient descent is not performed on this set
- unless you know that you need a DataLoader for your test set, you can simply do the inference on the whole test set at once; this is due to the fact that the test set is not part of the training loop and the inference is usually performed on CPU (unless you know that you need GPU, e.g. for real-time inference, or test set being so large that it does not fit into RAM but this isn't usually the case)